# intro.js with ionic 3 angular

Tags: angular, ionic3, intro.js

i am trying intro.js to get working with my ionic 3 angular app. the steps i did is:

install:
npm install intro.js --save

then in my index.html i have

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intro.js/2.7.0/introjs.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intro.js/2.7.0/intro.min.js"></script>
```

in my home.ts

```
    import introJs from 'intro.js/intro.js';

constructor() {
    console.log('Hello DynamicHomeComponent Component');
    this.expanded = false;

       // Initialize steps
        introJs.introJs().setOptions({
            steps: [
                {
                    element: '#id1',
                    intro: "Step one description",
                    position: 'right'
                },
                {
                    element: '#step_two_element_id',
                    intro: "Step <i>two</i> description",
                    position: 'bottom'
                },
                {
                    element: '#step_three_element_id',
                    intro: 'Step <span style="color: green;">three</span> description',
                    position: 'left'
                }
            ]
        });

  introJs.introJs().start();
  }
```

in html the id is added as below:

```
 <ion-row  style="border-top:1px solid #AFAFAF" text-wrap>
                          <ion-col [navPush]="accountPage" >
                              <ion-label class="widget-para-title widget-link" #id1>Accounts with open opportunities</ion-label>     
                         </ion-col>
                         </ion-row>
```

however nothing happens when i run the app. no error as well in the logs for introjs

Comment: I can be wrong, but I think the introjs element '#id1' could be a id of the element, no the angular reference.

Answer (score 2):

I changed :

```
import introJs from 'intro.js/intro.js';
```

to:

```
import introJs from '../../../node_modules/intro.js/intro.js';
```

code at .ts file :

```
   intro() {
  let intro = introJs.introJs();
// Initialize steps
intro.setOptions({
  steps: [
    {
      intro: "Hello world!"
    },
    {
      element: document.querySelector('#step1'),
      intro: "This is a tooltip."
    }
  ]
});
intro.start();
  }
```

code at .html :

```
  <ion-item step1 id="step1">
        <ion-label >Password</ion-label>
        <ion-input [(ngModel)]="password" type="password"></ion-input>

      </ion-item>
```

Comment: i am confused. you said didnt work and then also saying it worked. so plz clarify what worked and what did not

Comment: Sorry for the confusion , the one that doesnt work was tha intro js was overwritng the elements instead of highlighting them .

Comment: i am ending up in compile time issue saying --allowJS is false for intro.js

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply, check the code here https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-5d3qcz?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html