# How to implement walk through or tour in ionic 3?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, plugins, ionic2, ionic3

I want to implement App tour in my ionic3 app as shown in image below

[image]

Is there any trusted solution or plugins for **App tour or walk-through** for **ionic 3** and **angular 4** ?

Comment: You can easily integrate introjs library in your app. It has a lot of customization option. Take a look at https://introjs.com/

Comment: Ionic not provided App tour option they are provided  https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#slides

Comment: @AshrafulIslam is it comfortably working with ionic 3 and angular 4 ?

Comment: I have implemented tour with introjs with all of my requirements in angular. I hope you will not face any issue to implement it in ionic

Answer (score 8):

You can add a tour / walktrought /onboarding to you app by using intro.js:

1) install intro.js using npm. In you app directory launch

```
npm install intro.js --save
```

2) Import library in you app index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intro.js/2.7.0/introjs.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intro.js/2.7.0/intro.min.js"></script>
```

3) Create a page and put into page.ts header

```
import introJs from 'intro.js/intro.js';
```

4) Put into homepage.ts code

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.intro();
}

intro() {
  let intro = introJs.introJs();
  intro.setOptions({
  steps: [
    {
      intro: "Hello world!"
    },
    {
      element: '#step1',
      intro: "This is a tooltip.",
      position: 'bottom'

    },
    {
      element: '#step2',
      intro: "Ok, wasn't that fun?",
      position: 'bottom'
    }
  ]
  });
  intro.start();
}
```

3) Put in your page.html

```
<ion-content padding>
    <p id="step1">First step</p>
    <p id="step2">Second Step  </p>
</ion-content>
```

That's it!

Actually this is a simplified/tested version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46780985/intro-js-with-ionic-3-angular)

[A code sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-5d3qcz?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)

[Intro.js website for documentation](https://introjs.com/)

EDIT: This procedure works, but has an issue with chrome 66. Please refer [here](https://github.com/usablica/intro.js/issues/840) and find the solution by jwbeech. 
Anyway I quote the solution by jwbeech:

The issue is a css property attached to the root ion-app element: contain: strict;.
This appears to be a performance tweak for the ionic app which clearly has z-index issues in chrome.

contain: strict; is actually shorthand for contain: layout paint size style, changing it to: contain: layout size style; is enough to mitigate the problem.
Some background I found: https://termvader.github.io/css-contain/

The following SCSS should allow for this change only when the introjs tips are applied:

```
ion-app, ion-nav, ion-tab, ion-tabs, .app-root, .ion-page{
    &.introjs-fixParent{
        contain: layout size style;
    }
}
```

There may be other layouts that require this change not covered by the above style but that is the crux of the issue.

Comment: this is cool! How can I highlight some html element such as div or a button to reproduce the steps on how to use the app?

Comment: Started using it. But there are some conflicts beetween some components when I try to highlight some steps in the component. Causing the css to broke apart.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a badge to each menu you want to explain its role with css property display:absolute and its relative container will be whole content of that page.
Its algorithm is:
When user accept to have the tour option first label will be showed up with number and it's explanation label then if user click to first menu item it will be added to local storage to inform the application that user has read this info and so on for second and third ...
When user read each information it will be hidden for ever so it will have a boolean value.